# flickr gallery loading pictures from specified tag

Tags: jquery, json, flickr

Hey I have flickr gallery and i would like to load pictures from it to a div 'gallery' but only two first pictures with a specified tag defined in a 'data-category' should be load to that div.

I have html:

```
    <div data-category="clouds"  class="gallery"></div>
    <div data-category="mount" class="gallery"></div>
```

js:

```
$('.gallery').each(function(index) {
    var dataCategory = $(this).attr('data-category');
    (function() {
        var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            tags : dataCategory,
            tagmode : "any",
            format : "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_s.jpg");
                $("<img/>").attr("src", sourceSquare).appendTo(".gallery");
                if (i === 1) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });

    })();

});
```

The problem which I have is that now I load first two pictures from all specified tags into all 'gallery' divs. I supposed to load two pictures to 'gallery' but only with specified tag given in 'data-category'

Comment: What's the immediately-invoked anonymous function for?

Comment: @nnnnnn for `(function() { security })();` hahahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `.appendTo(".gallery")`, which appends to all matching elements. If I've understood what you are trying to do you need to append to the individual gallery element for the current outer `.each()` iteration.

Try something like this:

```
$('.gallery').each(function(index, el) { // <-- add parameter for current element
    var dataCategory = $(this).attr('data-category');
    var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
    $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
        tags : dataCategory,
        tagmode : "any",
        format : "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            var sourceSquare = (item.media.m).replace("_m.jpg", "_s.jpg");
            $("<img/>").attr("src", sourceSquare).appendTo(el); // <-- use el
            if (i === 1) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The `$.getJSON()` function is asynchronous, but its `.done()` function still has access to the `el` parameter from the containing function.

(Note: I've removed the immediately-invoked anonymous function since it didn't seem to add any value.)